# SQL Query not working for retrieving multiple results

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have the following columns present in my table "MyTable"

1. email_VC = for storing email purpose
2. EID = for email ID ( It's a primary key)
3. Status = It captures the status of the email whether it's "First","Second", "third"
4. Timestamp = time value

The following SQL Query only gives me the list of emails for Status = "First"

```
SELECT email_VC,Status,Timestamp 
    FROM Mytable
    WHERE event_vc = 'first'
    AND  Timestamp  BETWEEN '#sdt#' AND '#edt#'
```

I would like to have email address listed for Status = "Second" after it's done 
listing First ones' and then for the "Third" ones and so on..

But when I tried to modify above query as follows, it didn't work:

```
SELECT email_VC,Status,Timestamp 
    FROM Mytable
    WHERE event_vc = 'first' AND event_VC = "second"
    AND  Timestamp  BETWEEN '#sdt#' AND '#edt#'
```

Question #2:

Since EID is the primary key, however, if I want to count the unique email address in the
database, do you think that following SQL is good?

```
 SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(email_VC) as CountEmail 
     FROM   MyTable
```

My concern is that, I am not using any Primary key stuff in my SQL query.

Comment: Instead of AND use OR. if you have multiple conditions use IN ('first','second','third')

Answer (score 0):

Question 1.

Use `order by` with a `case` statement:

```
SELECT email_VC, Status, Timestamp 
FROM Mytable
WHERE Timestamp  BETWEEN '#sdt#' AND '#edt#'
ORDER BY (case when event_vc = 'first' then 1
               when event_vc = 'second' then 2
               when event_vc = 'third' then 3
               else 4
           end)
```

Question 2.

The correct syntax is:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT email_VC) as CountEmail 
FROM   MyTable ;
```

If you want to count the distinct emails, then this would be the correct syntax.